# Search that returns array of founds in wxPython?

Tags: wxpython

in wxPython Styled text, There is a FindText that finds first occurrence of text searched.
Is there a way to find all occurrences and put them into list or dict in one go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there's no built-in function, you can just use re.finditer on the contents of the StyledTextCtrl:

```
import re

full_text = my_stc.GetText()
search_string = 'a string to find'

matches = [i.start() for i in re.finditer(search_string, full_text)]
```